# mailgun-php SDK использование прокси

Tags: php, mailgun

Есть SDK https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-php

Как выполнять через него подключение к mailgun через свои прокси?

Буду благодарен за пример.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```php
<?php

$mailgun = Mailgun::create('your-api-key', 'https://your.proxy.server.adderss');
```